# Javascript or Jquery add, remove, copy rows to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to know how to or where to find this kind of code. Let me show you first

> ----- demonstration start ----- Add new line
>
> Line 1 - textbox | textbox | checkbox | radiobox | btnCopy, btnDelete,
>   btnAdd
>
> Line 2 - textbox | textbox | checkbox | radiobox | btnCopy, btnDelete,
>   btnAdd
>
> Line 3 - textbox | textbox | checkbox | radiobox | btnCopy, btnDelete,
>   btnAdd
>
> ----- demonstration end -----

I hope you understand what it is. Theses -boxes mean html input elements. btn- mean buttons that i am going to press.

I want like this.

After I press btnAdd @ Line 1, another new line of "Line 1" will appear without any data in textboxes just after Line 1, not the end of table, in this case Line 3.
After I press btnDelete except original Line 1, that line will be removed. That mean original Line 1, Line 2, Line 3 cannot be removed, but any other additional line will be.
After I press btnCopy @ Line 1, any data inserted in Line 1 will be copied to just-inserted new line.
These process will be the same for Line 1, 2 & 3.

However if I press "Add new line" @ the top of the demonstration, another new line will be inserted @ the end of the table(in this case line 3).

Any other ideas. The demonstration I shown above is going to used in my project, so it is better if it really can interact with database. Like looping through IDs for insert multiple datas, something like that.

Any idea ?

Comment: Well, start by writing some HTML to get the table format you want for the default three lines. When you're happy with that add in some jQuery event handlers for your buttons - start with some simple functions that just have `alert("copy button pressed");` or something so that at least you'll have some sort of structure where you can later add the actual copy/delete/add functionality. Then per-maybe-haps update your question with your new HTML and JS and ask for further help. (You seem to be asking for ready-made completed code, but if I write that for you I'll have to send a bill.)

Comment: easy to do add, remove, copy rows to table, but i cant make sence of all your other needs

Answer (score 1):

Sample Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zUAQC/11/

Can easily use it in different ways with different implementation.
There may be plugins available for this too.

Note - Its just a sample demo, with limited data just to get you started.

Comment: This is a good solution.  Just one tweak; Keesher wanted the line to be added directly after the line that the 'add' button was clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/zUAQC/12/

Comment: Thanks guys, but it's still not the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the DataTables plugin to do what you want.

Check it out: http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve my own problem and I manually created this. It worked well.
See the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy(name) {
    $(name).parent().parent().clone().insertAfter($(name).parent().parent());
    $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find("select").val($(name).parent().parent().find("select").val());
    $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find(".delete").attr("onclick", "remove(this)");
}
function add(name) {
    $(name).parent().parent().clone().insertAfter($(name).parent().parent());
    $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find("input").val('');
    $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find(".delete").attr("onclick", "remove(this)");

}
function remove(name) {
    $(name).parent().parent().remove();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">Select 1</option>
            <option>Select 2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="classItemCode" /></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add" onclick="add(this)">Add</a> | 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="copy" onclick="copy(this)">Copy</a> | 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete">Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It worked, as I wanted. If this code doesn't work, tell me.

I didn't add onclick attribute on delete link because that link is the original link. It shouldn't be removed. So I dynamically add onclick attribute for delete link in copy() and add() function.

(It worked perfect on Firefox. IE 8 and 9 worked too. But IEs worked only in one condition, I have to add onclick attribute @ delete link at the start. I will try to fix that.)